# Rotate base64string Image in c#

Tags: c#, image, base64

I ask me if it's possible to rotate a base64string image...

I make an app where I have pictures and want to check if the orientation is correct... If not I want to rotate the base64 image.

Does someone know if this is possible to rotate base64 images in c#.

Comment: You will have to decode the base64 string into an image and rotate the image.

Comment: `And I want to know if this is possible to rotate a base64string image with c#.` Yes.

Comment: @mjwills is it possible without converting to an image?

Comment: @Dominic Why specifically do you not want to 'convert' it to an image?

Comment: I ask myself if this is possible not that i don't want to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way you can do this is by doing something like this

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image))
{
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image.FromStream(memoryStream));
     g.RotateTransform(10); // Or any other angle 
}
```

You have to make references to `System.Drawing` and `System.IO`.